# Did I commit Shirk in my mind with these thoughts?

Tags: shirk, shaitan, children

I am a bit frustrated right now because I am not sure if i committed shirk… So, the conversation in my head went like this:

“What are we for Allah?” “The children of Allah??” with that phrase i DID NOT mean physically that we are the Children of Allah like the Christians believe, i meant that we are the creations of Allah swt his servants and that we belong to him, but i didn’t get the word “servants” in my head first… “Aren’t we the children of Adam?” “Can’t be because he didn’t create us…?” “Ah, i know it! We are the servants of Allah!!!“

Did I commit Shirk? My intention was only to believe that we are Allahs servants

Answer (score 0):

Shirk is well defined by Sharia and no one can interpret it by other than what came from the authentic texts (Quran and Hadith). in short shirk is to associate someone or something else with God regarding:
worshiping -> like you worship a man, idol, stone,...
Doaa ->like pray for other than God or asking for something that is God specific like asking some dead to give you child.
Accepting that some one (even yourself) to make haram as halal or halal as haram.

what you described is waswas and it is forgiven since you did not speak out load about it, in the authentic hadith, our beloved prophet PBUH said "God has forgiven for my ummah all what they speak to their souls if they do not speak it out load" sorry for the translation, means since they are keeping it inside their souls it is forgiven. he said also "shaitan will push thoughts in your heads till you say who created God, if you experience that say we believe in God and his messengers". God is more knowledgeable.

Comment: Thank you, May Allah reward you.